# How do I increase flame size in my outdoor fire pit?

Tags: outdoor, gas, fire-pit, fire

We have a built-in gas fire pit in our backyard and it all works but the maximum flame is doesn't provide enough warmth when I crank the valve to its max setting.

I've tried pulling off the knob but I have not tried unscrewing anything or using tools yet.

Do I need to remove the screws?

Do I need to shut off the gas to the entire house first?

[image: Close up of valve]

[image: Picture of Fire Pit]

Comment: Has it always been like this or is the low-flow condition something new?

Comment: Brand & model may help. There's a possibility that it has upgradable parts, but we can't tell since to us, it looks like "fire pit".

Comment: @JimmyFix-it We bought this house recently, so it's always been like this for us...

Comment: it is possible that it is designed for "show" , not for "heat"

Answer (score 1):

Gas appliances come in various sizes/capacities. So if this one isn't "big enough":

- Remove entire burner and control.
- Replace with larger capacity burner and control.

*Possibly also:* replace gas line, upgrade gas service to house, etc. depending on current capacity and size of new burner.

Comment: Also - you should have a gas supply valve for isolating the firepit. Make sure it's fully opened.

Comment: Thanks @ecnerwal. My guess here is that this is a restricted setting as part of the burner control. We have plenty of gas going into the house and into other appliances. We have two indoor gas-fired fireplaces that get plenty of gas. Is it possible that the control has some sort of limiter on it? If so, how could I investigate that?

Comment: If you want twice the output, or 10 times the output, you need a complete burner set up for twice the output, or 10 times the output. I strongly doubt that the 50K BTU/hr firepit and the 500K BTU/hr firepit are the same product built from the same parts. You also risk voiding your insurance by attempting to modify the burner you have to burn more than it's rated and listed for. There *might* be parts you can swap to larger capacity parts, there might not be. You'll have to figure out what you have there to even ask that question reasonably.